# Same og:title and title on a page

Tags: seo, title, open-graph-protocol

Does it make sense to render `og:title` and `<title>` that have the same value on a page?

Facebook & co take the `<title>` tag as fallback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems counterintuitive to me, but if we take IMDB as an example of proper implementation, we can see that they use the **same value for the `og:title` and `<title>` tags**.

To see for yourself, view source on an example movie like this one:
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1049413/

then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and you will see the following:

`og:title` - "Up (2009) - IMDb"

`<title>` - "Up (2009) - IMDb"

Interestingly the [open graph protocol website](http://ogp.me/) uses IMDb as an example but shows different markup than what IMDb actually uses. So it's possible that IMDb has changed their markup recently.

In any case, if it were wrong to the point that it breaks things then IMDb wouldn't be doing it, so I think it's safe to say you will be fine if you use the same value for your `og:title` and `<title>` tags.

Comment: "It seems counterintuitive to me" - What does? The fact that they could be the same?

Comment: @DocRoot Yes. I would think the `og:title` would read only as "Up" without the year and website name, because that's the title of the object itself, in this case the movie. But I'm not sure how that works, maybe the "object" that the open graph tag is describing is actually the page.